# Why does index.ctp render as text and not as html/php?

Tags: php, cakephp, view, file-extension

I tried researching this question on my own for awhile, but can't seem to pinpoint the solution. I'm working through the CakePHP Blog Tutorial, and at this section:  http://book.cakephp.org/view/1536/Creating-Post-Views

I create the index.ctp file with the code given by CakePHP. Then, when I open the index.ctp file in Safari, it simply shows the code given by CakePHP. It doesn't not render any HTML, nor does it pull the blog data from the database.

If I switch the extension from .ctp to .php, it renders HTML but it does not pull blog data from the database. My database is connected and has the correct information. I think there is an issue with the .ctp extension? Not sure. Has anyone else run into this kind of issue?

Comment: What URL do you call in your browser?

Comment: I assume you are running this using an appropriate web server with PHP enabled? Simple question i know but you have to ask...

Comment: Thx for the replies. Yes, PHP is enabled. I call http://localhost/cake/app/views/posts/index.ctp. If I call it without the .ctp extension, it says "URL not found on this server."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**First**, try this url:

http://localhost/posts/index

**Second**, you may have not mod_rewrite enabled in your development environment.
On ubuntu for example you can enable it with like this:

```
sudo a2enmod rewrite
```

(EDIT: restart apache afterwards)

**Third**: 
Check your .htaccess, you need mod_rewrite to be enabled. Also check the tutorial/cakePHP documentation to find out if you missed any step concerning .htaccess and the Rewrite Rules.

Comment: I did like you said. Mod_rewrite is enabled. I followed the tutorial procedure exactly. When I try to access http://localhost/posts/index, the file still cannot be found. Is the problem that I'm using localhost?

Comment: I've noticed a few other people had the same problem... there doesn't seem to be a solution.

Comment: I finally have it working. It was a combination of messing around with httpd.conf, mod_rewrite, .htaccess, and restarting apache. You helped me pinpoint the area in question. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 1):

RedEye,

1. call it the way like tacone wrote
2. make sure the file is in the correct path according to the conventions
3. make sure your server process has correct access rights for the file under concern

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure the `AllowOverride` is set to All (instead of None) in your sites-available/default file.